# starting activity from non main thread in Android

Tags: android, thread-safety

Please take a look at this code i found on android weekly [here](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/)

there is one method in that article and its called from a non-UI thread.  The author spawned another child thread and started an activity:

```
private void restoreApp() {
    // Restart activity
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MyActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ctx.startActivity(i);
}
```

My question is how is this possible to startActivity from a non-uiThread ? I thought this was discouraged or impossible.  is it ok ?

Answer (score 1):

Why you think "this was discouraged or impossible"? After all this is just a trigger for OS to start some new Activity? Maybe you confused it with the fact that "[Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)"?

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the `startActivityForResult` and indeed you can `startActivity` on non-UI thread.  It seems when you call `startActivity` it will run internally on main Thread. Note that in the AOSP `startActivity` calls `startActivityForResult` which executes on main thread:

```
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
if (mParent == null) {
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
        mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
            this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
            intent, requestCode, options);
}}
```